# kendo UI grid master/detail using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to implement a Kendo UI master/detail grid using the kendo angular directives:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <kendo-grid options="gridOptions">
            <div k-detail-template>
                   ???
            </div>
        </kendo-grid>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the controller, I've configured gridOptions on $scope to retrieve data from a rest service. This works fine. The grid displays this data. Now upon expanding a row, in detailInit function (defined on $scope.gridOptions) I make a second rest request to retrieve the child data associated with the expanded record. I want to display this data in the detail template.

My question is, how do I bind the HTML in the k-detail-template to the data returned from the second request? I tried assigning this data to $scope but then if I expand one row and then another row, both rows render the same detail. This is understandable as both detail rows will be bound to same scope.

In the following example on the Telerik website they bind to the dataItem.FieldName, but I don't think this is appropriate for me as I am not displaying a grid in the detail template.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular

I'm a newbie to Angular so apologies if I'm missing something obvious. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thank you.